# How do I get the output I wanted using If?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i am new to python and i wanted to make an introvert/extrovert quiz, and when i try to take the extrovert option, it doesn't + 1 on any of the extrovert answers.Instead, it will just +1 on the introvert  answers every time.
So what do I need to do in order to get this working?

```
extro = 0
intro = 0

print("1.------------------? : ")
d1a = input("A) ------------------.\n"
            "B) ------------------.\n"
            "[A/B]? : ")
if d1a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d1a == "A" or "a":
    extro = extro + 1


print("2.------------------? : ")
d2a = input("A) ------------------.\n"
            "B) ------------------.\n"
            "[A/B]? : ")
if d2a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d2a == "A" or "a":
    extro = extro + 1


print("3.------------------? : ")
d3a = input("A) ------------------.\n"
            "B) ------------------.\n"
            "[A/B]? : ")
if d3a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d3a == "A" or "a":
    extro = extro + 1



print("4.------------------? : ")
d4a = input("A) ------------------.\n"
            "B) ------------------.\n"
            "[A/B]? : ")
if d4a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d4a == "A" or "a":
    extro = extro + 1


print("5.------------------? : ")
d5a = input("A) ------------------.\n"
            "B) ------------------.\n"
            "[A/B]? : ")
if d5a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d5a == "A" or "a":
    extro = extro + 1


print("6.------------------? : ")
d6a = input("A) ------------------.\n"
            "B) ------------------.\n"
            "[A/B]? : ")
if d6a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d6a == "A" or "a":
    extro = extro + 1


if intro >= int(5):
    print ("you are an introvert")    

if extro >= int(5):
    print ("you are an extrovert")

print("you are an ambivert")



print("Thank you.")
```

Try and test it to see what i am saying

Comment: Do `d1a.lower()=="b"` , to compare multiple you may do `d1a=='b' or d1a=='B'` **or** `d1a in['b', 'B']`

Answer (score 0):

In python you cant do, '==' on multiple variables or characters unless you do them separately.

Right now when you write:

```
if d1a == "B" or "b":
    intro = intro + 1
```

Python thinks you are writing

```
if(d1a == "B") or ("b")
```

which will always be True since "b" is always itself.

Therefore to fix this, you will want to write

```
if d1a == "B" or d1a == "b":
    intro = intro + 1
elif d1a == "A" or d1a == "a":
  extro = extro + 1
```

Do this for all your inputs and you should be good.